# DDD in Android app : communication between aggregate and application service

Tags: android, domain-driven-design, ddd-service

I'm trying to apply `domain driven design` in an Android project. There is a common use case that the `User` wants to change his/her name and this new name should be synced with backend.

```
class User {
    // ...
    fun changeName(newName:String, service: AccountService) {
        val changed = service.changeName(newName)
        if (changed) {
           name = newName
        }
    // fire UserNameChanged event
    }
}
```

As above code snippet shows, can I inject an application service to do the synchronization with Backend, or there is a better way to do it ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the email with @[islandcoder876](https://twitter.com/islandcoder876)

> I generally run my CRUD operations through a repository.
>
> Here’s the flow: Pass user info to application layer > application
> layer construct the user model from the info > application layer call
> update method on the repository located in the infrastructure layer >
> repository run the necessary network call to send the user info to the
> backend.
>
> U can send the entire user object or just the fields u want to update.
>
> ---
>
> Anemic domain model is not as bad as it seems, there are arguments for
> and against it. Methods on domain models are normally business rule
> specific, I don’t think changing name is a business rule, that’s just
> a crud operation.
>
> I would say don’t complicate it by trying to make it fit into strict
> domain expectations. You won’t break anything with anemic models.